# how to send parameters array data from models to custom library and access the array in codeigniter..?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, models, libraries

i'm new in codeigniter. i have some problem for access arrays data in my custom library.

**my model**

```
    <?php if( ! defined('BASEPATH'))exit('No direct script access allowed');

      class Laporan_Gaji_M extends CI_Model {
          function __construct() {
          parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library("Payroll");
            $this->load->library("Payroll_J");
            $this->load->library("Payroll_G");
      }

      function data_ku() 
      {
       $sql = "SELECT a.idx, a.kode, a.jenis, a.nama, a.tgl_masuk, 
       a.status_karyawan, a.kelamin, a.status_tk, a.tunj_tetap, 
       a.tunj_jabatan, a.tunj_keahlian, a.medical_housing, a.upah_lembur, 
       a.gaji, c.nama AS nama_jabatan, a.kd_finger, b.* FROM 
       hrd_master_pegawai AS a LEFT JOIN hrd_laporan_absensi AS b ON 
       a.kd_finger = b.kode_finger AND b.bulan = '$bulan' LEFT JOIN 
       hrd_master_jabatan AS c ON a.jabatan = c.id_jabatan";

       $row = $this->db->query($sql);

          foreach ($row->result_array() as $value) {

            //print_r($value["jenis"]);

            $data = new Payroll_G($value); // i try send to my custom library and access the arrays data but not working.

          }
     } 
}
```

i try to get the `$value["jenis"]` in models and working fine,

but when i try to get `$value["jenis"]` in my custom library. i got message

> Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined index: jenis
>   Filename: libraries/Payroll_G.php**

**here my custom library**

```
<?php

class Payroll_G extends Payroll {

    function __construct($value = array()) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->hitung($value);
    }

    function hitung($value) {
    print_r($value["jenis"]);
    // message => Undefined index: jenis

    }
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Just a tip: your naming your class and file names incorrect follow codeigniter way https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: mr @wolfgang1983: done, but stil same mister. can you help me to solved my problem. thank you.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs when you initially load the library inside the Models's construct since $value is empty. And you also initialize the class inside a loop repeatedly.

I suggest you use codeigniter's function calls convention:

Model:

```
foreach ($row->result_array() as $value) {

        $data = $this->Payroll_G->hitung($value);

      }
```

Library:

```
class Payroll_G extends Payroll {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function hitung($value=array()) {
print_r($value["jenis"]);
}
}
```

Comment: thank you for you reply mr @chad. my problem is solved, finally i'm using **require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/Payroll_G.php');** not **$this->load->library("Payroll_G.php");**. it's work nice. Thank You.. :)